# HttpListener communication via tls 1.2

Tags: .net, ssl, httplistener

I am using HttpListener (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for standalone HTTP communication. 
Application developed with .NET v4.0. 
Is it possible to use TLS v1.2 in my application for communication with HttpListener?

Comment: Yes, httplistener will take the certificate from the windows keystore

Answer (score 0):

In short - yes, you can.
In long - it is a little bit more complex :-)

As far as I know security is controlled by the http.sys driver, which is used from the HttpListener.

You could configure what should be the SSL/TLS version used for ALL the applications on one and the same machine that are using those functionality.
But I think this is impossible in programmatic way and only for you application.
You can always use third party libraries of course, like OpenSSL.

Otherwise to configure you machine security layers you could refer some of those:
http://www.adminhorror.com/2011/10/enable-tls-11-and-tls-12-on-windows_1853.html

And test afterwards with OpenSSL client as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566

I supposed you are using MS .NET on Windows OS.
It is not quite the same with Mono.

Comment: I forgot: In order to use only TLS 1.2, you should disable SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 from the registry. And this will affect all the application of the machine that are using those functionality. Of course you could try to force TLS 1.2 use from client side.